# lftp remot file has data get to local file is empty

Tags: lftp

I'm running lftp and I've encountered the strangest error. Whether I run the mirror command or just a normal connection the results are the same.

1. Connect to the remote site
2. Login
3. Go to outgoing directory
4. ls see that file have data.
5. get any file
6. disconnect
7. ls local, file is empty.

It is the most bizarre thing, has anyone seen this before?

```
XXXXXXXXX@XXXXXXXXX ~>lftp sftp://XXXXXXXX -d
XXXXXXXXX@XXXXXXXXX ~>lftp XXXXXXX:~> user XXXXXXXXXXX
Password:
lftp XXXXX@XXXXX:~> ls
---- Running connect program (ssh -a -x -s -l XXXXXXXX sftp)
---> sending a packet, length=5, type=1(INIT), id=0
<--- Password authentication
<--- Password: XXXXXXXX
<--- Welcome XXXXXXXXXX
<--- got a packet, length=5, type=2(VERSION), id=0
---- protocol version set to 6
---> sending a packet, length=10, type=16(REALPATH), id=1
<--- got a packet, length=19, type=104(NAME), id=1
---- home set to /
---- path on wire is `/'
---> sending a packet, length=10, type=11(OPENDIR), id=2
<--- got a packet, length=45, type=102(HANDLE), id=2
---- got file handle 31636535316662352D343133352D343832352D626532662D663133383735633330366136 (36)
---> sending a packet, length=45, type=12(READDIR), id=3
<--- got a packet, length=111, type=104(NAME), id=3
---- file name count=1
---- eof
drw-------  XXXXXX/XXXXXXX 4096 2016-07-19 07:46:54 outgoing
---> sending a packet, length=45, type=4(CLOSE), id=4
<--- got a packet, length=17, type=101(STATUS), id=4
---- status code=0(OK), message=
lftp XXXXXXXX:/> cd outgoing
---- checking directory `/outgoing'
---> sending a packet, length=22, type=17(STAT), id=5
---> sending a packet, length=24, type=17(STAT), id=6
<--- got a packet, length=94, type=105(ATTRS), id=5
<--- got a packet, length=94, type=105(ATTRS), id=6
cd ok, cwd=/outgoing
lftp XXXXXXXXX:/outgoing> ls
---- path on wire is `/outgoing'
---> sending a packet, length=18, type=11(OPENDIR), id=7
<--- got a packet, length=45, type=102(HANDLE), id=7
---- got file handle 64333832336535352D643436372D346562312D393566382D646161646337653664613065 (36)
---> sending a packet, length=45, type=12(READDIR), id=8
<--- got a packet, length=2224, type=104(NAME), id=8
---- file name count=18
---- eof
-rw------- XXXXXXXXX 745 2016-07-12 05:35:04 XXXXXXXXX
-rw------- XXXXXXXXX 745 2016-07-13 05:34:12 XXXXXXXXX
-rw------- XXXXXXXXX 744 2016-07-14 05:49:18 XXXXXXXXX
-rw------- XXXXXXXXX 746 2016-07-15 04:50:29 XXXXXXXXX
-rw------- XXXXXXXXX 744 2016-07-18 01:31:48 XXXXXXXXX
-rw------- XXXXXXXXX 748 2016-07-19 07:18:50 XXXXXXXXX
-rw------- XXXXXXXXX 897 2016-07-12 05:40:03 XXXXXXXXX
-rw------- XXXXXXXXX 638 2016-07-13 05:35:07 XXXXXXXX
-rw------- XXXXXXXXX 930 2016-07-14 05:49:34 XXXXXXXXX
-rw------- XXXXXXXXX 1310 2016-07-15 04:50:44 XXXXXXXXX
-rw------- XXXXXXXXX 1089 2016-07-18 01:31:55 XXXXXXXXX
-rw------- XXXXXXXXX 780 2016-07-19 07:19:10 XXXXXXXXX
-rw------- XXXXXXXXX 1740 2016-07-12 05:45:36 XXXXXXXXX
-rw------- XXXXXXXXX 1731 2016-07-13 05:43:05 XXXXXXXXX
-rw------- XXXXXXXXX 1739 2016-07-14 05:52:30 XXXXXXXXX
-rw------- XXXXXXXXX 1806 2016-07-15 04:59:57 XXXXXXXXX
-rw------- XXXXXXXXX 1730 2016-07-18 01:31:55 XXXXXXXXX
-rw------- XXXXXXXXX 1732 2016-07-19 07:46:54 XXXXXXXXX
---> sending a packet, length=45, type=4(CLOSE), id=9
<--- got a packet, length=17, type=101(STATUS), id=9
---- status code=0(OK), message=
lftp XXXXXXXXX:/outgoing> get XXXXXXXXX
---> sending a packet, length=53, type=17(STAT), id=10
<--- got a packet, length=94, type=105(ATTRS), id=10             
---- file info: size=1732, date=Tue Jul 19 07:46:54 2016
---- path on wire is `/outgoing/XXXXXXXXX'
---> sending a packet, length=62, type=3(OPEN), id=11
<--- got a packet, length=45, type=102(HANDLE), id=11                 
---- got file handle 30393835326430302D366435362D343766322D623664302D306231636561626565346437 (36)
---> sending a packet, length=49, type=8(FSTAT), id=12
<--- got a packet, length=94, type=105(ATTRS), id=12         
---- file info: size=1732, date=Tue Jul 19 07:46:54 2016
---> sending a packet, length=57, type=5(READ), id=13
---> sending a packet, length=57, type=5(READ), id=14
<--- got a packet, length=1742, type=103(DATA), id=13        
---- data packet: pos=0, size=1732
---- eof
---> sending a packet, length=45, type=4(CLOSE), id=15
<--- got a packet, length=17, type=101(STATUS), id=14      
---- status code=1(EOF), message=
<--- got a packet, length=17, type=101(STATUS), id=15
---- status code=0(OK), message=
lftp XXXXXXXXX:/outgoing> exit
---- Disconnecting
XXXXXXXXX@XXXXXXXXX ~>ls -l
total 8
-rw-rw-r--. 1 XXXXXX XXXXX    0 Jul 19 07:46 XXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: Probably you have a problem with the local filesystem, try to fsck it.

Comment: Thanks, it actually works with just normal ftp not lftp. Think it could possibly be something with lftp specifically but still no luck getting it to work with lftp (which is what mos of my stuff uses).

Comment: Will try and get back to you though. Apologies - just realized who you are. Thank you for your tools.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me before. It's that the ssh key has not been added to the systems/users known_hosts file yet.

First you must ssh to the site normally. It will prompt you to accept the ssh key, say yes. Then disconnect and use lftp again and it should work now that the key is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Check out lftp 4.9.2 or newer version which fixed an issue for file download. It worked for me.

Please refer to https://github.com/lavv17/lftp/issues/312.

Comment: 4.8.4 is the last build available for rhel os.. do we need to compile the source?